# get last items inserted at the last hour

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm working with **codeigniter** framework and **mysql** database and i'm trying to get the last items from a table that inserted into the database in the last past hour

any one can help ?

Comment: `select ... where dateofinsert > now() - interval 1 hour`?

Comment: i didn't try any thing because i don't know about this issue a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code works :

```
    $date = strtotime('now') - 3600;
    $this->db->where('Date >',$date);
    $q = $this->db->get('news');
    if($q->num_rows()>0){
        return $q->result();
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Having your table `with TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column`, you just have to:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE timestamp_column >= DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR )
```

Table example

```
id | title | votes | timestamp
```